# How to upload location module zip codes for proximity search

Tags: location

This is driving me completely insane. I can't get the database to import to the zipcode table using phpMyAdmin. Looks like it is going, then a blank. Go to table and nothing. Trying to import the US data. Any suggestions? Using Drupal 7.3, location-7.x-3.0-rc5.

Had tried this with the latest Dev version of module, but caused issues with my entityform location field that I didn't have with rc5, and also couldn't import zip codes. Using it so people can add zip code among the other fields of info, then using a View to show the information in a table and run proximity search.

At first seemed to work as the results narrowed, but the distance kept showing 0.
Please please help.
Thanks
Daniel

Comment: What do you mean by `Looks like it is going, then a blank.` the page was blank or what?

Comment: I try importing the zip code .mysql file that was supplied with the module into the database using phpMyAdmin. Looks like the database is uploading for a few minutes, but then the main part of the screen turns blank white with the left panel of tables still listed. Nothing is added to the zipcodes table.

Comment: how big is the import file? Could it be larger than your allowed upload file size?

Comment: These location module zip code databases are small files, US is 3MB, and I had already increased upload file size. Have uploaded 60MB before with no problems. What is more frustrating is that I don't get an error, confirmation or any message, just a blank screen on the right side of the table list.

Comment: May be issue with format of the .mysql file, I'm a newbie so not sure. Beings with INSERT row to ID fields, not as a regular .slq format. 
INSERT INTO zipcodes (zip, city, state, latitude, longitude, timezone, dst, country) VALUES
('00210', 'Portsmouth', 'NH', '43.005895', '-71.013202', -5, 1, 'us'),
... for 43182 lines.

Worked around problem using SQL query, INSERT. Limited to 2000 lines, so did in pieces - pain in the rump. Don't know how to change that, if someone knows. Then I exported the table as .sql file so formatted with everything. Was able to import as normal into another database.